# CouchDB complex keys from a JToken

Tags: json.net

I am currently using Redbranch-Hammock to interact with a CouchDB database. I am able to perform simple queries of CouchDB views but become unstuck when trying to add complex keys to the query and I believe this is to do with how Redbranch-Hammock uses JTokens to represent the start and end keys (via the To(..) and From(...) methods on the Query object).

For example, If I have the following URL:

```
localhost:5984/db/_design/doc/_view/count_by_tag?startkey=["hyundai"]&endkey=["hyundai",{}]
```

How would I represent the end key **["hyundai",{}]** via a JToken object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're starting from the JSON string value and are trying to get a JToken from it, use `JToken.Parse`:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse("[\"hyundai\",{}]");
```

Or, you can manually create a JToken that resolves to the JSON string `["hyundai",{}]` like this:

```
JArray token = new JArray();
token.Add(new JValue("hyundai"));
token.Add(new JObject());
```

To convert a JToken to JSON, just use `ToString`:

```
string json = token.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I think my issue was with how to generate the {} in the endkey and now I know that's the equivalent of an empty JObject.